# EosioSwift - Cannot sign Tx - (self does not exist)

Tags: ios

I am trying to run the simple example in EOSIOSwift git repo (https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-swift), but it does not work.

The example is like this:

```swift
let transaction = EosioTransaction()
transaction.rpcProvider = EosioRpcProvider(endpoint: URL(string: "http://localhost:8888")!)
transaction.serializationProvider = EosioAbieosSerializationProvider()
transaction.signatureProvider = try EosioSoftkeySignatureProvider(privateKeys: ["yourPrivateKey"])

/// Actions can now be added to the transaction, which can, in turn, be signed and broadcast:

let action = try EosioTransaction.Action(
    account: EosioName("eosio.token"),
    name: EosioName("transfer"),
    authorization: [EosioTransaction.Action.Authorization(
        actor: EosioName("useraaaaaaaa"),
        permission: EosioName("active"))
    ],
    data: Transfer(
        from: EosioName("useraaaaaaaa"),
        to: EosioName("useraaaaaaab"),
        quantity: "42.0000 SYS",
        memo: "")
)

transaction.add(action: action)

transaction.signAndBroadcast { (result) in
    switch result {
    case .failure (let error):
        // Handle error.
        print("ERROR SIGN/SEND Tx", error, "Reason", error.reason)
    case .success:
        // Handle success.
        print("signed Tx.")
    }
}
```

When I run the code above I get from

```swift
print("ERROR SIGN/SEND Tx", error, "Reason", error.reason)
```

the following message:

```swift
ERROR SIGN/SEND Tx There was an unexpected error. Reason self does not exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the Transaction object would leave scope before the event loop would call the `sign` function, hence the `self does not exist`.

Maybe the error message could be extended with `self does not exist. object left scope. Consider instantiating object outside the current scope.`

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, the error isn't very descriptive. Are you defining the `Transfer` separately? That should be a struct. Example:

```swift
struct Transfer: Codable {
    var from: EosioName
    var to: EosioName
    var quantity: String
    var memo: String
}
```

Other than that, we use this library extensively and haven't run into this issue. I recommend checking out the iOS Example App to test out a working example: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio-swift-ios-example-app

That could serve as a working baseline for you.